# How do I display an image corresponding to a string value in a list item in android?

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I am developing an Android application with a list view and I want to diplay two textviews and an imageview in each listitem.

The text required for the textviews are stored in a server and is displayed on the listview. But I further want to add a corresponding image to each list item from the drawables folder, stored within the mobile app.

I access the text values using the link http://alvideobackend.azurewebsites.net/lesson/Physics
and receive the lesson number, name and subname. The images stored in the drawables folder are in correspondance with the lesson number. For example, lesson Number = 1, Image = 1.png

Please help me out in displaying the images in the list items.

SecondActivity.java

```
package com.example.acer.videoapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView listView1;
    Toolbar toolbar1;
    String subjectName;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> lessonList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        //setting title to toolbar
        toolbar1 = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
        toolbar1.setTitleTextColor(getColor(R.color.white));

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle!=null) {
            toolbar1.setTitle(bundle.getString("description"));
            subjectName=bundle.getString("engdescription");
        }

        lessonList = new ArrayList<>();
        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        new GetLessons().execute();

        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                HashMap<String, String> lesson = lessonList.get(i);
                intent.putExtra("number", lesson.get("number"));
                intent.putExtra("name", lesson.get("name"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //set back button on toolbar
        toolbar1.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back);
        toolbar1.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });



    }

    /* Async task class to get json by making HTTP call */
    private class GetLessons extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SecondActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String url = getResources().getString(R.string.lessons_url, subjectName);
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    // Getting JSON Array
                    JSONArray lessons = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                    // looping through All lessons
                    for (int i = 0; i < lessons.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = lessons.getJSONObject(i);

                        String number = c.getString("lessonNo");
                        String name = c.getString("lessonName");
                        String engname = c.getString("lessonEngName");

                        // tmp hash map for single lesson
                        HashMap<String, String> lesson = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        lesson.put("number", number);
                        lesson.put("name", name);
                        lesson.put("engname", engname);



                        // adding lesson to lesson list
                        lessonList.add(lesson);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Please check your Internet Connection");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    SecondActivity.this, lessonList,R.layout.list_item1, new String[]{"name","engname",}, new int[]{R.id.lname,R.id.lname1});
            listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

        }


    }

}
```

list_item1.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:editable="true"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="0dip"
            android:paddingTop="20dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lname1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="20dip"
            android:paddingTop="0dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="13sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general method could be to build a data model for your list items, then when selecting a new item in the list, update the image from the data model.

A specific way of doing it could be to have your image filenames loaded into an array in the same order as they appear in the list, then, when an item is selected in the list, display the image from that index of the array.

Comment: how do I display the image from the array to each listitem?